# Prevent browser caching of PDF generated with Dompdf

Tags: php, http-headers, dompdf

I'm generating a PDF document using [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). The code looks something like this:

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('This is my HTML');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('My_file.pdf', ['Attachment' => false]);
```

In other words, completely standard. The problem I have is that, when I "stream" the PDF content to the client, it comes with the HTTP header:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

which means the document will probably be cached by the browser. This is apparent when I change the document and use the same link to open it again. I will see the old version. Pressing F5 (on Windows) solves this, but I would like to change the header to something like:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

If I set the header in PHP like this:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
```

before streaming the PDF, it gets overwritten, and I obviously cannot change it once the streaming has been done.

I cannot find a way to do this.

**Does anybody know how to change the HTTP header that DomPDF uses?**

Comment: related github issue opening here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/3098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying on the built-in stream method you can manually stream the PDF. Borrowing from Dompdf's internal logic:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('...');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
if (headers_sent()) {
    die("Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent");
}
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($pdf, "8bit"));
header(\Dompdf\Helpers::buildContentDispositionHeader("inline", "output.pdf"));
echo $pdf;
flush();
```

Comment: This is an excellent idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: This works for me. If you make some minor changes I will approve this answer. 1. The `Cache-Control` should, of course, be set to `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`, because that was my question. 2. `echo $tmp;` should be `echo $pdf;`. 3. Less important, but I couldn't get the `Helpers` class, don't know why, I simply replaced it by `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"');`. 4. You could replace `mb_strlen($pdf, "8bit")` by the trusted `strlen($pdf)`.

Comment: Fixed 1 & 2, thanks for catching my sloppy copy pasta. I added the namespace to the Helpers call in case the issue was due to a class definition collision. As for `mb_strlen`, I kept it since MBString is required by Dompdf but it's a valid modification.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way of changing the header which is being set in `src/Adapter/CPDF.php` on line `914`

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
```

Maybe possible to extend the class and modify the `stream` function.

Comment: This is what I thought as well. However, I'm not a fan of extending a class I don't own, nor does this really change the problem. For now I add a sufficiently randomized extra parameter to the URL, so the browser will see the URL as something unique. That works, but it's weird that DomPDF insists on a cached document.